# Refactor or Relocation of data range validation in Views

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

im new to stack and dont know if its the best way to post, but im learning. I have a view in Django to validate some data range fields that i have built with bootstrap, But im learning about managers, querysets and im trying to follow best practices. I feel that i can refactor this view, or shrink in size using forms and etc. Could you give me some tips? this views is large? can be refactored or relocated to other files, like forms? thanks in advance.

After all what im doing is verify a data range with all these ifs, if the fields are empty show all data, if one is empty show all bellow or above the non empty date, and if both are filled, only test is enddate is bigger than startdate, and in each case i have different context and render, so it gets big!

https://github.com/paasxx/crypto-site/tree/sqlite_to_postgre/app_crypto

```
def market(request, crypto):
    crypto_name = crypto
    crypto_model = getModelByName(crypto)

    sd = request.GET.get("startDate")
    ed = request.GET.get("endDate")

    min_date_table = crypto_model.crypto_objects.first_date().date
    max_date_table = crypto_model.crypto_objects.last_date().date

    crypto_data_all = crypto_model.crypto_objects.all_data()

    if sd == None and ed == None or sd == "" and ed == "":
        crypto_data = crypto_data_all

        context = {
            "currencies": currencies,
            "crypto": crypto_name,
            "crypto_data": crypto_data,
            "min_date_table": min_date_table,
            "max_date_table": max_date_table,
        }

        return render(request, "app_crypto/crypto_list.html", context)

    else:
        if datetime.strptime(ed, "%Y-%m-%d") < datetime.strptime(sd, "%Y-%m-%d"):
            messages.warning(
                request, "End Date must be greater than Start Date, Please try again."
            )
            crypto_data = crypto_data_all

            context = {
                "currencies": currencies,
                "crypto": crypto_name,
                "crypto_data": crypto_data,
                "min_date_table": min_date_table,
                "max_date_table": max_date_table,
            }

            return render(request, "app_crypto/crypto_list.html", context)

        else:
            if sd == None or sd == "":
                crypto_data = crypto_model.crypto_objects.lesser_or_equal_date(ed)

                context = {
                    "currencies": currencies,
                    "crypto": crypto_name,
                    "crypto_data": crypto_data,
                    "min_date_table": min_date_table,
                    "max_date_table": max_date_table,
                }

                return render(request, "app_crypto/crypto_list.html", context)

            elif ed == None or ed == "":
                crypto_data = crypto_model.crypto_objects.greater_or_equal_date(sd)

                context = {
                    "currencies": currencies,
                    "crypto": crypto_name,
                    "crypto_data": crypto_data,
                    "min_date_table": min_date_table,
                    "max_date_table": max_date_table,
                }

                return render(request, "app_crypto/crypto_list.html", context)

            else:
                start_date = datetime.strptime(sd, "%Y-%m-%d")
                end_date = datetime.strptime(ed, "%Y-%m-%d")
                crypto_data = crypto_model.crypto_objects.between_dates(
                    start_date, end_date
                )

                context = {
                    "currencies": currencies,
                    "crypto": crypto_name,
                    "crypto_data": crypto_data,
                    "min_date_table": min_date_table,
                    "max_date_table": max_date_table,
                }

                return render(request, "app_crypto/crypto_list.html", context)
```